# How to return greater value of the period for unique id combination?

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-asa

If the `paid_amount` is not NULL or greater than 0 for the greater value of the `period_id` for that `section_id` and `store_id` combination, then the store would get a Y value for `checked` column. Here is the query I created based on the criteria that is listed above:

```
select section_id, store_id, paid_amount, period_id, secttion_id + store_id as unique_id
from store_data 
where paid_amount is not null and paid_amount > 0
order by store_id, paid_amount desc;
```

Query above produces data below:

```
section_id  store_id  paid_amount  period_id  unique_id
3604        30545     10000.00     3          30545
3604        30545     5000.00      2          30545
5967        32105     8470.00      3          38072
5967        32105     8470.00      2          38072
1367        46144     23456.00     2          47511
1367        46144     23456.00     3          47511
1367        46144     23456.00     4          47511
1367        46144     23456.00     5          47511
1376        72181     19975.00     2          73557
```

I need to get only one row of data if there are multiple. For example for `unique_id` `30545` I only want the row with the greater amount. In that case that should be row with the `paid_amount` of `10000.00`. If row only has one record I only need that row. Is there a simple way to achive this in the `Sybase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since sybase doesn't support window function , here is one way:

```
select s1.* from store_data s1
join (
  select unique_id , max(paid_amount) paid_amount
  from store_data s2
  where s2.paid_amount is not null and s2.paid_amount > 0
  group by s2.unique_id
) s2
on s1.unique_id = s2.unique_id
and s1.paid_amount = s2.paid_amount
```

however if you still have duplicates , you can narrow the condition :

```
select s1.* from store_data s1
join (
  select unique_id , max(paid_amount) paid_amount, max(period) period
  from store_data s2
  where s2.paid_amount is not null and s2.paid_amount > 0
  group by s2.unique_id
) s2
on s1.unique_id = s2.unique_id
and s1.paid_amount = s2.paid_amount
and s1.period_id = s2.period_id
```

Comment: I assume that where clause should be applied as well. Correct?

Comment: @espresso_coffee yes,

Comment: I tried example above, but I'm still getting two records for the same store_id instead of one. I'm not sure if the example above is accurate.

Comment: Yes, they do have same amount.

Comment: first , my subquery was based on store_id , but now I noticed you wanted per unique_id , so see updated query ,

Comment: second if you still getting duplicates , see my second query , if you still have duplicate add more condition like what I did ,

Comment: The original query was joining the paid_amount column and that was causing the result set with more than one row. After I applied period_id in the join clause the data was accurate. That filter eliminated the duplicates.